# Override get, set in Entity Framework Database First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have class from model first (EF 4.4 .Net 4.0):

```
public partial class Test
{
    public int Id {get; set; } 
    public int Date { get; set; }
    //other fields...
}
```

I can't change database model but I need to override get and set in this class.
Something like that:

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(TestMetadata))]
 public partial class Test
 {
     public class TestMetadata
     {
         private int data;
         public DateTime Date
         {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.Today.Date;
            }
            set
            {
                date = value.Day;
            }
        }
    }
```

This approach dosen't work. Is it any possibilities to override get set in partial calss?

Comment: Describe what you want to achieve and why would you do that? Give a real-life scenario.

Comment: I have an old system which date and time keep in int field (in Database). I rewrite old system to C#+EF and I haven't change database structure (because of compatibility).

Comment: But in you first code property Date is directly in Test class however in next is in TestMetadata. Can you explain what functionality do you want to achieve?

Comment: First class is from Database (model first) and I can't change them because after update I'll lose chenges. I need get Date from database, convert it into date format and show like (ex. yyy/mm/dd) and next save (set) data into database after coverted into Int (ex. 77768).

Answer (score 2):

My workaround.
Something like that:

```
public partial class Test
    {
        public DateTime DateSi
        {
            get
            {
                return ConvertIntToDate(Date)
            }
            set
            {
                Date = ConvertDateToInt(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

In C# I use Test.DateSi (not mapped) and EF save into Database field Date with proper Int value. I only have to remember to use in C# DateSi instead of Date.

Comment: You can even make the `Date` property private. EF will be able to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a part of solution. I dont understand where (what property) do you want to save converted date. There is no chance to save int to datetime field.

```
public partial class Test
{
    string format = "yyy/mm/dd";

    public string DateFormat { get { return Date.ToString(format); }
}
```